# HM-10 Bluetooth module IC identification

Tags: identification

Does anyone know what the component in the picture is?  It is on an HM-10 Bluetooth module.

[image: the component in question]

[image: the entire module]

Where it connects to. Found using the multimeter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpHqEJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Should be "translator"?  https://www.electronicproducts.com/hands-on-review-hm-10-ble-module-and-its-mysterious-clones/

Answer (score 1):

If you schematic was somewhat correct, it looks like input protection TVS diode.

Intended to short over voltage to the 3.3V rail, e.g. electrostatics.